# How do I fix my progress bar from glitching?

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar, custom-controls

I am experiencing an issue where the progress bar is behind, if you click [THIS LINK](https://tunechestmusic.000webhostapp.com/) and go to the second song you will see that the progress bar is all messed up. If anyone has a solution please help! [This is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW45m.jpg) of what the problem is. Also this is all the coding I think necessary to solve the problem.

```js
var timer;
var percent = 0;
var audio = document.getElementById("audioPlayer");
audio.addEventListener("playing", function(_event) {
  var duration = _event.target.duration;
  advance(duration, audio);
});
audio.addEventListener("pause", function(_event) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
var advance = function(duration, element) {
  var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
  increment = 10 / duration
  percent = Math.min(increment * element.currentTime * 10, 100);
  progress.style.width = percent + '%'
  startTimer(duration, element);
}
var startTimer = function(duration, element) {
  if (percent < 100) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      advance(duration, element)
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```css
#timeline {
  width: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  margin-top: 27px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
}


/*Grabable Playhead*/

#playhead {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -10.9px;
  background: black;
}

.progress {
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
  transition: width .1s linear;
}
```

```html
<audio id="audioPlayer" preload="true" ontimeupdate="initProgressBar()">
        <source src="https://tunechestmusic.000webhostapp.com/sleepy.mp3">      
    </audio>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!--Audio Player Interface-->
  <div id="audioplayer">
    <button id="pButton" class="play"></button>
    <div id="timeline">
      <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
      <div id="playhead"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, your code works for me (Chrome 81). What browser do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some key things to make it work

The first thing is that your `play` button doesn't actually do anything. Try adding an event to handle the clicking of the play button and play the audio

```
var playButton = document.getElementById('pButton');

playButton.addEventListener('click', e => { audio.play(); });
```

The second issue I see is that your `audio` tag is supposed to call `initProgressBar` but that function doesn't exist.

```
<audio id="audioPlayer" preload="true" ontimeupdate="initProgressBar()">
```

I added a placeholder function for you to fill in. If you don't need this function, remove it from the HTML.

```
function initProgressBar() {
  // TODO: What goes here?
}
```

After you add the click event in, the audio plays when clicked and the progress bar makes the correct progress. However, your circle doesn't move with the progress. I'm assuming you just haven't gotten that part yet.

```js
var timer;
var percent = 0;
var audio = document.getElementById("audioPlayer");
var playButton = document.getElementById('pButton');

playButton.addEventListener('click', e => { audio.play(); });

function initProgressBar() {
  // TODO: What goes here?
}

audio.addEventListener("playing", function(_event) {
  var duration = _event.target.duration;
  advance(duration, audio);
});
audio.addEventListener("pause", function(_event) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
var advance = function(duration, element) {
  var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
  increment = 10 / duration
  percent = Math.min(increment * element.currentTime * 10, 100);
  progress.style.width = percent + '%'
  startTimer(duration, element);
}
var startTimer = function(duration, element) {
  if (percent < 100) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      advance(duration, element)
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```css
#timeline {
  width: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  margin-top: 27px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
}


/*Grabable Playhead*/

#playhead {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -10.9px;
  background: black;
}

.progress {
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
  transition: width .1s linear;
}
```

```html
<audio id="audioPlayer" preload="true" ontimeupdate="initProgressBar()">
        <source src="https://tunechestmusic.000webhostapp.com/sleepy.mp3">      
    </audio>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!--Audio Player Interface-->
  <div id="audioplayer">
    <button id="pButton" class="play">Play</button>
    <div id="timeline">
      <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
      <div id="playhead"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The bar moves but the 'ball' doesn't - not sure if you noticed that or not.. just FYI.

Comment: It's mentioned in my answer.

Comment: And what would I put inside the this?   `function initProgressBar() {
  // TODO: What goes here?
}`

Comment: I don't know. You put that on your element but didn't define the function for it. I'm not sure what you want that function to do. Do you need it? (hence the TODO comment)

Comment: Yes I'm not sure what to put for the function.

Comment: ...This is starting to sound like you copied/pasted someone's code and don't know how to tailor it to your needs. If that's the case, I would strip your example down to a bare minimum working example and build from there.

Comment: Its not copied and pasted although I have taken parts off codes from different pieces of work and customized it, although I don't understand the progress bar element at all. Please help me.

Comment: I would suggest breaking out the progress bar logic into it's isolated "app" for now. Get a bare minimum working example of pressing a button and it progressing over 10 seconds or something. Once you have that down, you should be able to bring that into your app. If you have a specific question around that, feel free to post a new questions and I'm happy to take a look. Part of the problem when learning something like this when you're not familiar with it is that it's challenging because you're covering too much at once.

Comment: My fault @mwilson - I prob should have read your answer before commenting lol..

Comment: @mwilson great news! I just fixed it and the progress bar is running smooth, all I did was change the transition width (not sure why that worked). One last quick question, what is the code to show the current time?

Comment: Current time of what? Please open a new question for this with the specifics.